# MySQLI Prepared Statement Not Binding Properly

Tags: php, mysqli

Any reason why the following code won't work?

```
$dbconnection = db::getInstance();  //this is a singleton db class

$stmt = $dbconnection->prepare("SELECT `id` from `table` where `username`=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($uid);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $uid;
```

The same connection method is used elsewhere, and it works there. The only difference on that other page where it works, is that there are multiple rows fetched, not just one.

**edit:** I get no error message.  `echo $uid` just doesn't output anything.  It's supposed to echo the user's ID from the DB (yes, that query from the DB works properly, tested it).

Can you suggest a good way to debug this if you can't immediately see a problem?

**edit:**
Tried switching `execute() and bind_result()` positions, with no difference.

**edit**
I finally got an error/warning:

> *Warning: mysqli_stmt::mysqli_stmt() [mysqli-stmt.mysqli-stmt]: Couldn't fetch db*

**SOLVED**

Okay.  I solved my problem.  I guess you're not supposed to close the db connection when using a singleton class?  I wasn't aware of that.  The problem was, that after the "logging-in" function was being called, I did a `$dbconn->close();`  And later on I was grabbing the same instance, so the db connection was closed.

Comment: What error message / undesirable output do you get, and what were you expecting?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Maybe check that your inputs are as you expect?, so var_dump($username); etc. Or just for debugging purposes, actually put the username into the query to see if it's an issue with binding the input or binding the output, etc.

Comment: I just posted the db class in case that might have a problem.

Comment: @Rich Adams - I did the var dump...$username is set properly.  I finally was able to generate the error, edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Okay. I solved my problem. I guess you're not supposed to close the db connection when using a singleton class? I wasn't aware of that. The problem was, that after the "logging-in" function was being called, I did a $dbconn->close(); And later on I was grabbing the same instance, so the db connection was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to always check the return values of each database call... most of them return at least a success/failure boolean.  And you can use mysqli->error to emit something intelligible if the return value isn't what you expect.  Here's an example:

```
  $stmt->bind_result($uid)
     or die("Error binding result - ".$stmt->error) ;
```

The best thing about doing that is you can leave the debugging code in, and it will be useful in narrowing the problem if there's ever a weird database connectivity problem or something.

Comment: oh, you've got exception handling in your model... so my example using die() may not be what you want.  But you can still check each return value.

Comment: very nice suggestion thank you.  however, as i edited my post above, i finally was able to output some errors/warnings.  and the first one is that it cannot fetch the db.  is there something wrong with my singleton class, since i can connect to the db from another page.